# How to fix the Unknown error in accessing S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Added permissions to  in the bucket policy. But getting unknown error while accessing the bucket.
Please see the below. Here I want sample-developer-role to access the bucket sample-data-pr.

```html
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow List from developer",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::432575145856:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::771245789651:role/sample-developer-role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::771245789651:role/sample-ec2role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sample-data-pr/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sample-data-pr"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

While trying to download from console. Got the below error.

```html
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>4D55A0961BF2D54F</RequestId><HostId>UMnF3edCkxb5wVk+H7fmOXFal/uWQZ39KUI4L=hfgsfsfttthf</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "unknown error"?

Comment: In the Access tab in the bucket console, Unknown Error is shown

Answer (score 1):

AWS S3 console access requires more permissions that you've provided. The permissions you've given are suited for **programmatic access only**, but not for generic S3 console access.

You can check following two **AWS blogs** with instructions how to set it up, depending on your requirements:

- [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)
- [How can I grant a user Amazon S3 console access to only a certain bucket or folder?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I have shown here is the bucket policy. Should I update in IAM policy for accessing this bucket?

Comment: @Judil Yes, if you want to add your developers access to s3 console.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to download the file? Clicking on it, or right clicking and using Download as? The former will not work unless the bucket is set to public.

Comment: using Download as

Comment: @Judil in that case you need to check that the policy attached to the role allows to perform such action